# Setting up virtualenv in windows with specific interpreter

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a number of django projects organized with the following directory structure using win7 (I'm using GIT_BASH/mingw for my command line) :

```
envs--s1--project1
        --project2        
python275--
```

I want to create a virtualenv inside s1 using python275 as the interpreter so the directory structure looks like:

```
envs--s1--project1
        --project2
        --Include
        --Library
        --Scripts
python275--
```

I tried:

```
/c/envs/s1
$ pip install virtualenv
sh: pip: command not found
```

How can I set up this up?

Comment: Have you installed pip in your virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't have pip installed on your system. If you have installed using the get-pip.py installer you need to make sure the Scripts directory of you python installation is included in your PATH environment variable.

For more detail regarding installing pip check out the [doc](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)